# Communications link failure with Online-database

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm using mysql-connector-java-5.1.38 and It worked well on localhost. But when I connect to my database on openshift, I got trouble:

```
Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
```

This is my code to connect to server:

```
public static final String DATABASE =   "jdbc:mysql://<database address>:3306/my_database";
public static final String DB_ACCOUNT = "my_userame";
public static final String DB_PASSWORD = "my_password";
...
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DATABASE, DB_ACCOUNT, DB_PASSWORD);
```

Please help me. Thank you so much!

Comment: are you able to connect mysql with any ide like... mysql workbench?

Comment: Ya, I can connect to localhost Mysql server.